# Devices not getting displayed under /dev when using modprobe

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I use PCAN Driver for Linux v8 developed by PEAK SYSTEMS.

After successful compilation when tried to load the Linux Kernel Module (LKM) named `pcan`

```
sudo modprobe pcan
lspcan -T -t -a
```

Devices are not getting displayed under `/dev`

Note: I have not connected actual device or hardware in my PC.

Is it expected behavior? Or regardless of actual device connection, those should get displayed? Which is expected behavior?

Reason why I am asking is, when doing `insmod` with my own LKM, I got the devices under `/dev`.

Comment: It depends on the driver and what it does. In your case seems the original driver doesn’t do anything because no hardware present, but your custom one ignores hardware absence.

Comment: @user2699113, @Acorn Thanks for your comments.. 
My purpose is, to bring virtual devices under ```/dev``` regardless of device connection. 
I have this in my code for USB Structure probe member Callback function registration.
```pcan_drv.usbdrv.probe = callBackFunction;``` 
Is there anyway to invoke this function by anychance ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it expected behavior? Or regardless of actual device connection, those should get displayed? Which is expected behavior?

In general, a driver should only create the `/dev` entries for devices that it is actually handling.

Since you don't have the hardware, it is normal that the driver did not create anything.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that PCAN driver doesn't create entry in /dev on its own, and you need to do it manually. Not every driver creates those files automatically. Try to look at /proc/devices file if there is the device you are expecting. If yes - try to create appropriate device node in /dev using mknod.

Edit: If you have no connected device in your PC - how driver could recognize it and create appropriate files in /dev?

Comment: @Acorn Thanks for your comments.. 
My purpose is, to bring virtual devices under ```/dev``` regardless of device connection. 
I have this in my code for USB Structure probe member Callback function registration.
```pcan_drv.usbdrv.probe = callBackFunction;``` 
Is there anyway to invoke this function by anychance ?